How to create a Kotlin Map from Javascript?
I have a Kotlin Multiplatform method that takes a Map as an argument. How can I call it from JavaScript?
I have seen utility functions to create a Set or List from JavaScript but cannot figure out how to write one for creating a Map.

Can you provide some code of what you've already tried?
